Twilio: How to transcribe a recorded dialed call?
I'm developing a Typescript app where I'll make some phone calls using Twilio. My goal is to save the calls' transcriptions.
These are the current attributes I'm passing to Twilio's Dial verb:
record: 'record-from-answer',
recordingStatusCallback: 'handleRecordings'

From the Dial docs, there's no option to activate transcriptions for the calls. In the recordingStatusCallback callback I also don't receive anything regardings transcriptions, just the Call/RecordingSid and some more info. I also don't see a way to retrieve the transcription based on the RecordingSid in the docs.
How can I achieve my goal? Thanks
